# I want to ingest data using NIFI to two directions one in HDFS and one in Oracle Database. Is it Possible?

Tags: apache-nifi

We are using Nifi to ingesting data in HDFS. Can at same time same  data be ingested in Oracle or any other database using NIFI?

I need to publish same data two places (HDFS and Oracle Database) and do not want to write two subscribe program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NiFi has processors to get data from an RDBMS (Oracle, e.g.) such as QueryDatabaseTable and ExecuteSQL, and also from HDFS (ListHDFS, FetchHDFS, etc.). It also has processors to put data into an RDBMS (PutDatabaseRecord, PutSQL, etc.) or HDFS (PutHDFS, e.g.). So you can get your data from multiple sources and send it to multiple targets with NiFi.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate your reply. Can you point some example or tutorials how to send data to multiple target. We are getting data from SOA QUEUE and want to send to Oracle Database and HDFS both.

Comment: Once your data is ingested into NiFi (I guess via InvokeHttp or something), you can make two downstream connections, one to something like PutDatabaseRecord (for Oracle) and PutHDFS (for HDFS). The flow file will be transferred to both `success` relationships thereby letting you send to multiple targets.

Comment: Thank you . I will try out this and will let you know. I have started working on this and was expecting same.